# Can i have table inside another table for database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to have database table inside another table is this possible for `SQL`?
Imagine I have billions of posts, articles, in a database table and in another tag table i have these fields:

- id
- post_id
- tag_id

So i have a tag with has a relationship to one post and the id/line number is 150.000.000, if I try to open this tag link in a browser the script takes anlyses for 150 million lines/tags and the system finds it.

But if i could have sub-table for each tag, the system doesn't need to analyse 150 million lines. And it can directly access these posts which is related to any tag... I think this is very important for large databases..

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want ?!

Comment: [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: Why do you need that? You can join tables to fetch data from two or more tables at once. Also you can save data in json format but I don't see the point

Comment: Databases can handle 150m records **just fine**, as long as you set appropriate indices and use sensible queries. You have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/476). Your actual problem is that your database/queries are not optimised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, no. I don't know what you are trying to do, but I guess what you want to do can be done by creating more than one table, then creating relations between them. If you join these tables in your queries, I believe you can achieve what you want to do.

If you can be more specific about the question and topic, I believe you can get better answers.

Edit:

Since you edited the question, now I see what you intended to achieve. You're right, running queries on huge tables everytime is not preferable. But since your tag queries for the posts will generally return the same set of data, there is a much easier way than you have thought: caching. I think you should first try to implement better caching algorithms, instead of making changes in the database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a table inside another table at the back end. I presume you are thinking of triggering an action by performing another action which is completely possible in SQL by several functions such as JOINS, CTE or triggers. You can relationships between multiple tables with perfectly valid constraints just like a grid / list in front end.

If you can provide your requirement clearly, we can promptly point you on the best ways to work it out.